# What are the defaults in Rails for connecting models to partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials, convention-over-configur

In Rails 7, there appears to be some defaults that connect models to partials. If so, can someone point me to the documentation?

I am working through the "Depot" demo in Sam Ruby's "Agile Web Development with Rails 7".  This demo uses a generator to build a scaffold for a "Product" table. This block appears in `index.html.erb`:

```
  <div id="products" class="min-w-full">
    <%= render @products %>
  </div>
```

and there is a file named `_product.html.erb` in the `views` directory.

So, there must be a convention that maps an array of model objects to a partial of the same name; but, I can't find anything that documents that --- including on this page: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

I do see that you can pass an object to `render` if that object responds to `render_in`; but, `Product` does not appear to either implement or inherit this method.

Normally, I'd be happy using the "obvious" behavior; but, I'm teaching a class on Rails, and I'd like to be able to explain this "magic" (or at least know where it is documented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented under [Rendering Collections](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections):

> There is also a shorthand for this. Assuming `@products` is a collection of `Product` instances, you can simply write this in the `index.html.erb` to produce the same result:
>
> ```html
> <h1>Products</h1>
> <%= render @products %>
> ```
>
> Rails determines the name of the partial to use by looking at the model name in the collection.

I realize that's not the documentation for the source code, if that's what you're looking for, but I think you can regard it as authoritative.

Answer (score 2):

[`to_partial_path`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_partial_path) method defines what partial is rendered, which is [part](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb#L80) of the rendering process:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def to_partial_path
    "some/partial"
  end
end
```

Which means `render @product` will render `some/_partial`.

Comment: If the method isn't implemented explicitly, default value is determined by the [`_to_partial_path`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3/activemodel/lib/active_model/conversion.rb#L110-L118) class method.